# Binding properties of a custom class to a WinForms DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have written a class, and would like attributes of it to be displayed in a DataGridView control. However, only some of the properties are available to bind to columns. How can I make all my public properties available to bind to columns? Below is my class, the IndividualServices property isn't showing up in the designer while the others are.

```
Public Class Patient
Private _name As String
Private _id As String
Private _services As New List(Of Service)


Property Name As String
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _name = value
    End Set
End Property
Property ID As String
    Get
        Return _id
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _id = value
    End Set
End Property
Public ReadOnly Property Services As List(Of Service)
    Get
        Return _services
    End Get
End Property
ReadOnly Property TotalServices As Integer
    Get
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each s As Service In _services
            i = i + s.Count
        Next s
        Return i
    End Get

End Property
ReadOnly Property IndividualServices As Integer
    Get
        Return _services.Count
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub Add(sName As String, sCode As String)
    Dim bool As Boolean = False
    If _services.Count = 0 Then GoTo firstThrough
    For Each s As Service In _services
        If s.Name = sName Then
            s.Add(1)
            bool = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not bool Then
firstThrough:
        Dim newSer As New Service
        newSer.Name = sName
        newSer.Code = sCode
        newSer.Count = 1
        _services.Add(newSer)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What all have you tried so far?  Have you tried returning "_services.Count" instead of "Services.Count"?

Comment: No change in the designer, but thanks for pointing that out! Made the edit. I added it as a property only for the DataGridView, otherwise I had been calling Patient.Services.Count

Comment: Off-Topic but strongly recommended: avoid using `GoTo` statement.

Comment: Your code works properly, make sure you have a valid build. Also make sure you have added all columns to `DataGridView`. For example if you have added that column recently after binding the grid to that type, you should manually add the column to your grid.

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding my solution solved the problem, thanks for the suggestion! Will take these steps more often in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, cleaning and rebuilding the solution solved my problems! Will take these steps more often in the future.